# Can't find Python executable

Tags: python, node.js

`Error: Can't find Python executable "D:\Python", you can set the PYTHON env variable. at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)`

I do have python installed (2.7.14) in `D:\Python`, and I have setup the environment variables [image]

I also tried `SET PYTHON=D:\Python`.

`python` command from command line works fine.

`python.exe` is in `D:\Python`
[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It turns out that `node-gyp` does not take variables from windows environment, and you have to set them like this:

`npm config set python D:\python`

I was installing `sharp`, not `node-gyp`, that's why I did't pay attention to their documentation that has this command:

`npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`

which will install all for you and set the paths. I used this command and was finally able to successfully run `npm install`.

**Note:** you need to run this command as administrator

Comment: Thank you for this.  I was trying to install chimp.js and running into the same problem.  I had to install from an admin command prompt to get the windows-build-tools to install properly.

Comment: What about macos?